# Receiving a segmentation fault

Tags: nasm

Hi I am working on a factorial program for an assignment. I am receiving a segmentation fault and I am not sure why.

```
section .data  ;constants
    nums:  db  13,21,14,25,34,63,23,23,42,0x32 ;numbers sum = 290 ave 29
    len:   db  $-nums
    nln:   db  0xA
    msg:   db  "Average",0xA
    mlen:  db  $-msg
section .bss   ;variables
    spot:   resb 1
    total:  resb 4
    ave:    resb 4
    ob1:    resb 1
    ob2:    resb 1
    ob3:    resb 1
section .text  ;code
    global _start

_start:
    sub esi,esi 
    mov byte [total],0
```

a loop to go through all variables of the nums vector

```
loop:
    mov esp,[nums+esi]
    call ptln
    call convert_ascii
    call print_conv
    add [total],esp
    mov ecx,total
    add esi,1
    cmp esi,10
    jmp ptave
    jmp loop
```

to print the average

```
ptave:
    mov esp,[total]
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg
    mov edx,mlen
    int 0x80
    call convert_ascii
    call print_conv
    jmp exit
```

just printing a new line

```
ptln:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,nln
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80
    ret
```

exit command

```
exit:
    mov ebx,0
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80

convert_ascii:
    mov byte [ob1],0
    mov byte [ob2],0
    mov byte [ob3],0
    xor edx,edx
    mov eax,10
    div esp
mov [ob3],edx
    div esp
    mov [ob2],edx
    div esp
    mov [ob1],edx
    ret

print_conv:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,ob1
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80

    mov ecx,ob2
    int 0x80

mov ecx,ob3
int 0x80
```

I know the problem starts at the $mov esp,[nums+esi]$ line but I don't know what is wrong. I added the full code because I don't really understand what I am doing.

Comment: Why not just step through the code in your debugger to see what's going on ?

Comment: can you give me one's name i have been working on vim and on linux

Comment: One what?  Debugger?  How about gdb?

Comment: As @pat says, just use `gdb` if you're on Linux - assemble your code with `-g` and then debug the executable with `gdb ./a.out`

Comment: ok i ran it and it only told me what I already knew that is in the loop but i all ready knew this

Comment: You need to *step* through the code, not just run it. As you step through the code, examine the contents of registers and variables to see what is going on, and how this differs from your expectations. This should then give you enough insight to indentify and fix your bugs.

Comment: i am trying that i looked up the tutorial and it is only telling me that the error is on the first line of the loop section. which i already knew now what I need to know is what is the problem. trying to step isn't working i just get program not running

Comment: You realize that `call` and `ret` (and probably `int`) depend on `esp`, which you are modifying in your program? Rule of thumb: Do **not** use `esp` as a general-purpose register unless you're really, _really_ sure that it's ok to do so.

Comment: no no i did not I will try changing registers

Comment: Michael that was the problem could you please copy your comment into an answer so I can mark it as solved with proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` and `ret` instructions (and probably `int`) implicitly use the stack, and therefore require `esp` to point to the correct location (i.e. the current top of the current thread's stack; or the current top of *some* stack that you've set up yourself). Since you're using `esp` as a general-purpose register in your code you end up accessing memory locations that your application most likely doesn't have access to as soon as you execute e.g. a `call`:

```
mov esp,[nums+esi]
call ptln  ; call tries to push the return address onto the stack, but esp
           ; now contains one of the values from nums: OOPS! -> segfault
```

Rule of thumb: Do **not** use `esp` as a general-purpose register unless you're really, *really* sure that it's ok to do so.

---

Another potential problem is that `nums` is accessed as if it was an array of doubleword, even though it's declared as an array of bytes.